# Empty ClientContext on Java lambda handler (but working on JavaScript handler)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

From my web application I am invoking a lambda function with parameters:

```
{
  FunctionName: 'myFunctionName',
  ClientContext: btoa(JSON.stringify({ myCustomObject }))
};
```

When my function is implemented in JavaScript (in the 'Node.js 12.x' runtime), I can normally access context.clientContext.myCustomObject and all the contents are available.

However, when I switch the implementation of the same function to Java (I tested with "Java 11 (Corretto)", "Java 8 (Corretto)" and "Java 8" runtimes), without making any changes to the client, the client context appears to be empty (although it is not null):

```
context.getClientContext(): lambdainternal.api.LambdaClientContext@2353b3e6
context.getClientContext().getCustom(): null
context.getClientContext().getClient(): null
context.getClientContext().getEnvironment(): null
gson.toJson(context.getClientContext()): {}
```

I was expecting to see myCustomObject inside the context.getClientContext().getCustom() map. Is this a bug? Isn't Client Context available to lambdas implemented in Java? Or am I missing something?

My Java handler code is as follows:

```
package com.mycompany;

import java.util.Map;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;

public class LambdaMethodHandler {

  public Map<String, String> handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

    if (context.getClientContext() == null || context.getClientContext().getCustom() == null || context.getClientContext().getCustom().get("myCustomObject")  == null) {
      return Map.of(
        "statusCode", "403",
        "body", "Forbidden. Please provide custom object in Client Context."
      );
    }
  
    return Map.of("body", "Hello World LambdaMethodHandler - " + input);
  }

}
```

From the docs I see that the ClientContext in general should be used only for mobile apps (which is not the case here). However if it worked for the JavaScript implementation I would expect it to consistently work for other languages.

Comment: Can you post your Java logic that uses the Lambda runtime API so the community can see it.

Comment: @smac2020 Thank you for the suggestion, I added the Java handler code to the question.

Comment: That is much better to help the community spot the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a ClientContext that can be serialized into the java object.

If you check the [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/api/client/EventHandlerLoader.java#L872) it's using GSON to deserialize it into a `LambdaClientContext` object.

I.e. it should work if you pass an object like this

```
{"custom": {"key1":"value1"}}
```

Comment: That explains it. I wish I had seen that source earlier instead of blindly fighting the issue. By trial and error I found the same solution (we posted simultaneously), but I didn't know the reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I found out that if the Client Context object provided in the lambda invocation has a key "custom":

```
{
  FunctionName: 'myFunctionName',
  ClientContext: btoa(JSON.stringify({ custom: { myCustomObject } }))
};
```

The contents can be successfully retrieved by calling

```
context.getClientContext().getCustom().get("myCustomObject")
```

I still don't know whether this is by design or an unexpected quirk of the java handler implementation. I won't mark this as the accepted answer, hoping that someone will be able to provide a better explanation about my mistake or about the correct way to use the Client Context.